# With Lazy Loading in hibernate Db connection is not released

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am not able to find the solution why with Lazy Loading in hibernate Db connection is not released .

I am using Hibernate version 4.

How can I get resolve this problem?

Comment: please clarify what you are doing (show us some code) and what the exact problem is. As it stands this question is really vague.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading works within a single transaction. A single transaction is bound to a single connection. So you can't close the connection and still have Lazy Loading.

Comment: So how can we close the connection .

Comment: Exit the outermost method annotated with `@Transactional` assuming you are using annotations to control transaction scope.